# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$zip' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I think I got zip library installed correctly:
[image: zip installed]
But I got the following error running line

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$zip' (T_VARIABLE) in /Zip.php
>   on line 107

I am a php newbie, anyone know why this happens? Did I not do something? thanks a lot.

Comment: Most likely a missing `;` on the line before `$zip = new ZipArchive();`.

Comment: Yo, thanks, this question was too dummy, I did miss the semicolon. ...